# Adding default data to model - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, qweb

I'm adding default stock location data to a custom module,

First added on `stock.location` like this:

```
<record id="location_stock" model="stock.location">
    <field name="name">ReparacionUnidades</field>
    <field name="location_id" ref="stock.stock_location_locations_virtual"/>
    <field name="usage">production</field>
    <field name="company_id"></field>
</record>
```

This works fine, but when I try to add this very same location to actually my module, as a default stock_location, it throws me this:

> ParseError: "null value in column "vehicle_id" violates not-null
>   constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (441, f, 1, null, 7,
>   2017-01-12 17:49:15.871444, null, null, 1, null, null, services,
>   2017-01-12 17:49:15.871444, 2017-01-12, null). " while parsing
>   /home/kristian/odoov9/danisan/fleet_stock/data/location_data.xml:10,
>   near 
>     ReparacionUnidades  ReparacionUnidades

This is how I'm adding this to my module:

```
<record id="location_default" model="fleet.vehicle.log.services">
    <field name="x_location_src_id">ReparacionUnidades</field>
    <field name="x_location_dest_id">ReparacionUnidades</field>
</record>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create the record 'location_default' without setting the required fields of the 'fleet.vehicle.log.services' model.

Let see the model definition :
[fleet.vehicle.log.services model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTvQj.png)
So the required fields are vehicle_id, cost_type and cost_id. You need to set each of these fields.

Comment: Thank You very much